# WSO2-IS 5.11.0 - Update User - SCIM Rest Java Client Application

Tags: wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to update an user information created in WSO2 Identity Server having LDAP as user store and using SCIM Client Java Application. [Consuming SCIM Rest Endpoints from JAVA Client Application](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/consuming-scim-rest-endpoints-from-a-java-client-application/)

I've configured the certificates and hostname to this application and tested the `CreateUser` class with the "hasini@gmail.com" user and it worked.

[image]

**My problem is when I try to use the `UpdateUser` class for this user. WSO2IS server shows an error:**

```
[2021-06-24 14:57:15,979] [f9d70e10-be8c-4f84-944f-394070b187db] ERROR {org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint} - 
Internal Server Error while updating User org.wso2.charon.core.exceptions.CharonException: 
Error while updating attributes of user: hasini@gmail.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.updateUser(SCIMUserManager.java:570)
    at org.wso2.charon.core.protocol.endpoints.UserResourceEndpoint.updateWithPUT(UserResourceEndpoint.java:546)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.resources.UserResource.updateUser(UserResource.java:268)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor307.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Profile information could not be updated in LDAP user store for user : hasini@gmail.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:205)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.provider.impl.SCIMUserManager.updateUser(SCIMUserManager.java:554)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:191)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Profile information could not be updated in LDAP user store for user : hasini@gmail.com
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.handleException(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2135)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doDeleteUserClaimValue(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1081)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.deleteUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4177)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: mail=hasini@gmail.com: 
[LDAP: error code 64 - naming attribute 'mail' is not present in entry]; remaining name 'mail=hasini@gmail.com'
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3097)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2895)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1409)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:257)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:167)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:156)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doDeleteUserClaimValue(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1077)
    ... 73 more
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.wso2.samples.is</groupId>
   <artifactId>wso2is-identity-samples-scim</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

**Is it the best way to integrate a React Application with WSO2-Identity Server or there is a better way?** I want to create, update, delete, change user's password, etc, by my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to integrate React Application with WSO2 IS, it would be better if you can make use of SCIM REST endpoints [1](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis) for create, update, delete, change user's password

FYI you can refer [2](https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps) [3](https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/master/apps/console/src/features/users/api/users.ts), React application developed by WSO2 IS.

Comment: But why is not working update from SCIM Rest?